# Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : Expected #1, Actual #2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have two tests. First test work correctly. Second test looks like as first test. However, I get exception, when I run the second test.

The first test:

```
public void GetCurrentBalance_Should_getting_rigth_balanse()
{
    // Arrange
    double balance = 10;

    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = mocks.Stub<IUnitOfWork>();
    unitOfWork.Stub(svc => svc.AccountRepository.Get()).Return(new List<Account> {new Account { Balance = balance }}); 

    AccountService accountService = new AccountService(unitOfWork); 

    // Act
    mocks.ReplayAll();
    var result = accountService.GetCurrentBalance();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(balance, result);
}
```

The second test:

```
public void WithdrawMoney_Balance_should_decrease_when_money_been_withdrawn()
{
    // Arrange
    double balance = 10;

    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = mocks.Stub<IUnitOfWork>();
    unitOfWork.Stub(svc => svc.AccountRepository.Get()).Return(new List<Account> { new Account { Balance = balance } });

    AccountService accountService = new AccountService(unitOfWork);

    // Act
    mocks.ReplayAll();
    var result = accountService.WithdrawMoney(1); // this line is different

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(balance - 1, result);
}
```

Part of my service:

```
public class AccountService : BaseService, IAccountService
{
    public AccountService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    public double WithdrawMoney(double amountOfMoney)
    {
        var currentBalance = GetCurrentBalance();

        if (currentBalance < amountOfMoney)
        {
            throw new BusinessLayerException("error!");
        }

        var lastAccount = GetLastAccount();

        if (lastAccount == null)
        {
            throw new BusinessLayerException("error!");
        }

        lastAccount.Balance -= amountOfMoney;

        unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Update(lastAccount);
        unitOfWork.Save();

        return lastAccount.Balance;
    }

    public double GetCurrentBalance()
    {
        var lastAccount = GetLastAccount();

        if (lastAccount == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return lastAccount.Balance;
    }

    private Account GetLastAccount()
    {
        var lastAccount = unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Get().FirstOrDefault();

        return lastAccount;
    }
}
```

I get the following call stack:

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : IUnitOfWork.get_AccountRepository(); Expected #1, Actual #2.
   at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.DoGetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.MethodRecorderBase.GetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.DoMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.Invocation.Actions.RegularInvocation.PerformAgainst(IInvocation invocation)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IUnitOfWorkProxy2936ffa6dea844258ad88f7a7e99dbc0.IUnitOfWork.get_AccountRepository()
   at Service.AccountService.GetLastAccount() in AccountService.cs: line 90
   at Service.AccountService.WithdrawMoney(Double amountOfMoney) in AccountService.cs: line 61
   at ServiceTest.AccountServiceTest.WithdrawMoney_Balance_should_decrease_when_money_been_withdrawn() in AccountServiceTest.cs: line 48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem by changing the second test. I change one line:
from:

```
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = mocks.Stub<IUnitOfWork>();
```

to:

```
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = mocks.DynamicMock<IUnitOfWork>();
```

But it seems to me that this is a bad solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

follow below rules for Rhione mock test

for using Rhino Mocks just follow the steps as under with Mock Object:

1.Create mock by: mockrepository.CreateMock();

2.Record your expactations: in Record Block.

3.call ReplayAll to tell rhino Mocks that you are done with recording

4.MOST IMP. STEP:Call expected method here for example: mockMyRhinoImplementation.HelloRhinoMocks(“ABC”)

NOTE: Must need to pass the same arguments what you have recorded else it will again throw ExpectationViolationException.

5.Call VerifyAll();

So, the differene between both the tests are tht one method is having argument and the another does not have...try to use like below

```
double number = 1;
var result = accountService.WithdrawMoney(number);
```